# Audacity doesn't work with pulseaudio anymore

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, audacity

**UPDATE:** Today's upgrade to `alsa-lib-1.1.7-2` fixed the issue. (2018-11-23)

---

Arch Linux, up-to-date. As so often, a `-Syu` upgrade broke things again. This time it's audacity. Usually audacity, and **any** other playback/record app would show up in `pauvcontrol` - Not audacity anymore. I could use `pauvcontrol` to choose sink and source from which I want to record or playback audio using audacity - not anymore.

In audacity's preferences it only says `ALSA` in the top dropdown, im not sure if that is supposed to be like that or if it said `PulseAudio` before. There aren't even all my devices in the playback tab. Same goes for the recording device selection, but the loopback device I need to record from is there, so that works.

[image: preferences]

But now I wanted to playback sound from audacity too and it just doesn't work anymore. It doesn't list my USB playback device and when I set it to `sysdefault` I just get an error.

```
$ pulseaudio -v
pulseaudio 12.2

$ audacity --version
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-params>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-params.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-params.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-midigate>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-midigate.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-midigate.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-fifths>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-fifths.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-fifths.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-metro>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-metro.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-metro.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-amp>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-amp.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-amp.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-sampler>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-sampler.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-sampler.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-scope#Mono>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-scope.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-scope.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Duplicate plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-scope#Stereo>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... found in file:///usr/lib/lv2/eg-scope.lv2/
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: ... and      file:///usr/lib64/lv2/eg-scope.lv2/ (ignored)
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-params>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-midigate>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-fifths>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-metro>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-amp>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-sampler>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-scope#Mono>
lilv_world_add_plugin(): warning: Reloading plugin <http://lv2plug.in/plugins/eg-scope#Stereo>
```

Not sure if those warnings mean anything, it won't print the version.
The package is `audacity-2.3.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Full log of the console when starting audacity:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1099:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline:CARD=0,DEV=0
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline:CARD=0,DEV=0
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.Loopback.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4555:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5034:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM phoneline
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1099:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
```

Even though I'm not sure if those errors are because of ALSA and maybe completely unrelated to the PulseAudio issue.

Comment: This is very old but I am having the same problem on an up-to-date system. If anyone else has any ideas what _else_ it could be then that would be helpful.

Comment: @Jachdich There's a not-too-little chance that it is a similar bug that will be fixed in a future update. Have you tried downgrading alsa-lib to a previous (known to be working) version as suggested in the answer below?

Comment: Yeah I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=241523) I found [this bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60579). This is an issue with the latest (1.1.7) version of `alsa-lib`. Downgrading it to your previous version should work around the issue for now:

`pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/alsa-lib-1.1.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Answer (score 2):

I'm running 1.1.8-1 of alsalibs and had a similar issue.  Starting audacity changed my output to the internal speaker. 
I got it working with `alsactl restore`, then `pulseaudio -k`, but it's wonkey. 
VLC and audacity can't seem to both use the output at once.

Comment: Sounds like one of the two are trying to access the hardware directly, rather than using pulseaudio (which will lock it up, as in other devices can not access it at the same time). Seems very unrelated to the issue my question is about though.